# Compress PDF obtained using PDFMerger (PHP)

Tags: php, shell, pdf, merge

I am currently build a PDF from many existing pdf files. I am using [PDFMerger](http://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/releases/view/37934) that is working great. My trouble is that I obtain a very heavy file and I want to reduce it using a ghostscript command.

My PHP script is

```
$pdf = new \Clegginabox\PDFMerger\PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/one.pdf', '1, 3, 4');
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/two.pdf', '1-2');
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/three.pdf', 'all');

//You can optionally specify a different orientation for each PDF
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/one.pdf', '1, 3, 4', 'L');
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/two.pdf', '1-2', 'P');

$pdf->merge('file', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf', 'P');

$command = "ghostscript -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf"
exec($command, $output, $retval);
```

The command `exec($command, $output, $retval);` seems to be not executed (`$pdf->merge('file', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf', 'P');` seems to stp the PHP execution). How can I execute it?

Comment: does the command work on the command line? be careful with paths when using exec and the OS, full paths to be safe

Comment: @nogad, Yes the command works well. I have tried to write `$pdf->merge('file', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf', 'P'); echo "Done";` but I never obtained the result "Done"

Comment: are you running into any recorded errors? Or are you exceeding your memory limits?

Comment: I have not obtained any errors yet and the `merge` command gives me the right files but how can I check if the `merge` command return error?

Comment: Effectively I add an error (Exception) from PDFMerger. I have remove it and now, it is working well. Thanks for your help